# Vagrant box laravel/homestead fails to start because of wrong disk attachments

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

During `vagrant up` command I saw that it is generating `settler_default_xxxxx` folder in my virtual machines folder, and then it renames the folder to `homestead-7`, and then tries to run the machine and fails with:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state.
```

When I look at the machine, I see that it has wrong hard disk attachment. The disk still points to the path in `settler_` folder which no longer exists. I have to manually remove the attached disk and attach the right one in the `homestead-7` folder instead.

Why doesn't Vagrant rename the disk attachment to `homestead-7`? Am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, then is it Vagrant's, Laravel's or VirtualBox's bug?

My config:

- Vagrant 1.8.1
- VirtualBox 5.0.14
- VAGRANT_HOME points to V:\VAGRANT_HOME
- VirtualBox File -> Preferences -> Default Machine Folder points to V:\

Computer:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- 8GB RAM